# integrating library causing errors C++

Tags: c++, windows, directx, static-libraries

I am working in a VC++ 2010 windows project that incorporates DirectX SDK (June 2010), and another team generated a physics library to incorporate into the program. When I go through and perform all required calls to the library, and all. and I followed the directions that they gave to integrate the library:

```
extract the director containing the .h files into my c:\
```

in C/C++>general>Additional Include Directories place

```
c:\physics_core        // without additional additional dependencies
```

then in Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies place

```
C:\physics_core\PhysicsCore\Release\PhysicsCore.lib    // without additional additional dependencies
```

then include the manager, and use the namespace provided wherever the methods, and objects need to be called (intellisence even attempts to suggest auto completes correctly). but then my compiler throws the following list. I am pretty sure that the first 6 have to do with the library itself, and the others have to do with directX.

```
1>  PhysicsCore.lib(PhysicsMgr.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
1>LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/LTCG' specification
1>PhysicsCore.lib(PhysicsMgr.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in MainCore.obj
1>PhysicsCore.lib(Box3D.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in MainCore.obj
1>PhysicsCore.lib(Circle3D.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in MainCore.obj
1>PhysicsCore.lib(Box2D.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in MainCore.obj
1>PhysicsCore.lib(Circle2D.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in MainCore.obj
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__UpdateWindow@4
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ShowWindow@8
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateWindowExW@48
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegisterClassExW@4
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__LoadCursorW@8
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__DefWindowProcW@16
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PostQuitMessage@4
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__InvalidateRect@12
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__AddFontResourceExW@12
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetWindowRect@8
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__DispatchMessageW@4
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__TranslateMessage@4
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PeekMessageW@20
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__UnregisterClassW@8
1>MainCore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RemoveFontResourceExW@12
1>C:\general\...\Engine\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals
```

the thing is when I roll the program back to before I integrate the Physics Library everything works like it is supposed to. the people who created the library tell me that it works fine on all the system(s) they tried to used it on, but they never attempted to use it in a windows program, and they assure me that it is nothing to do with it being a windows application. when I asked if they used any special flags like the first linker warning states they said that they used no such flag (the lead programmer didn't even know what they were, or how to set them). the build before integrating physics had directX working fine even rendering.

any help would be great.

Update: changed the Linker>input>Additional Dependencies to

C:\physics_core\PhysicsCore\Debug\PhysicsCore.lib 
may need to change this under release to be the original

that fixed the first 6 errors, but the unresolved externals still exist

Update:
situation solved.

the all errors were solved by taking 2 actions regarding the same properties line.

1 insuring that a debug build of the Library was being used during debug mode.

2 checking the dependencies of the library in question, and including them if there is any overlap. as the compiler first checks the dependencies list of any libraries being used, and then checks the dependencies of the project. if there is any overlap the first one stands, and all those there after are ignored, but if the include dependencies flag is not set to true the compiler will not include them.
so the corrected line to solve the situation was in the Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies needed to be changed to:

```
C:\physics_core\PhysicsCore\Debug\PhysicsCore.lib    // include additional dependencies
```

again thank you for all your help.

Comment: Don't ignore this: *warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library*  Conflicting runtime libraries can cause all sorts of problems, though you will *usually* see redefinition of library functions.

Comment: @EdS. but how do I resolve them. that's the big thing. all of those calls are in the rollback build, and its fine what is going on.

Comment: Are you trying to link the *Release* version of `PhysicsCore.lib` with the *Debug* version of your program?

Comment: @Praetorian ok that solved the first set of problems, but now the unresolved externals still exist.

Comment: You need to link to `user32.lib` and `gdi32.lib` as well.

Comment: @ildjam I found 7 of each on my system which one( windowsSDK, MicrosoftSDKs, or one of the sub directories of these) could you give a general path. when I did a search for this it shows up in the buildlog.htm of the version before adding the libary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to modify one of the properties lines in order to clear all errors.
first change was that the directory of the .lib had to be rectified to match that of the build Debug with Debug, and release with release.

the other issues were resolved when the "inherit from parent, or project default" check box in the library Linker was reactivated. (though the direction to incorporate the library said otherwise.